# Need to generate randoms alphabets on each time page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to generate a random letter from A-Z multiple times on my page when it refresh or reload. may be i am a bit confused here whether i can create a array for storing all alphabets and use .random method of javascript . i'm pretty sure we need to use random here. But there is any other simple way for doing this in jquery.

Comment: This should get you started: http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2011/08/jquery-generate-random-password.html

Comment: You stated what you want to do, but you did not state your question. Show some code and ask your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a simpler way of doing this with jQuery. You'll have to use the `random` method to generate the desired text. Try something like:

```
function generateRandomText(n) {
    var text = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        text += String.fromCharCode(65 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 32 * (Math.round(Math.random())));
    }
    return text;
}
```

The `Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)` bit picks a letter, and `Math.round(Math.random())` gives a random 0 or 1 value, that decides the case(upper and lower respectively)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/VFLvG/)

Comment: how could this works on page load.

Comment: In my fiddle I have put the `document.getElementById('text').innerText = generateRandomText(20);` line inside the `onclick` event of the button. Put it inside the `document.onload` event

Comment: this seems to not working i have put your code in document.onload event but it shows nothing

Answer (score 1):

use `random` with `String.fromCharCode` as,

```
String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random()*26+65))
```

This will give you a random alphabet each time.